# How to force permission "android.permission.CAMERA" to be added to manifest in Codename one

Tags: android, codenameone, android-permissions

I am trying to show a live preview of the rear facing camera in Codename One. I use for that the native interface (I am targetting Android first).

To allow my app to use the camera without messing up with build hints, I added these lines in my Main Form :

```
if (Capture.hasCamera()){
     Dialog.show("Appareil photo détecté", "Votre matériel est bien équipé d'un appareil photo!", "OK", null);
    }
```

I did that because [Codename One blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/androids-permissions.html) stated

> android.hardware.camera & android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO - are triggered by com.codename1.Capture

However while debugging the app with the sources I got from CN1 under Android Studio on a real device (API LEVEL 19 aka Kit Kat) I always got a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`.

After a while I realized that the exception was due to the lack of the following permission in manifest.xml :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>`

*Please note that as stated in CN1 blog the line `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` was already added by CN1.*

Now that I've added this line the live preview is well shown.

Why is this permission not automatically added in the manifest, should I really add it to the build hint ?

Moreover I have another project that uses the Camera to take photo and save them on the phone and the Camera permission is neither shown (in Android Application Info) nor requested during app installation whereas it works perfectly well. Please note that e.g. Twitter App shows "Take photos and record videos" in the app permissions so it does not seem to be a problem with my phone hiding camera permission.

**EDIT November 20th 2016 :**

Indeed [Android Developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest) states that

> Note: If you are using the camera by invoking an existing camera app, your application does not need to request this permission.

That's why CN1 does not require this permission!

Thanks for helping me getting the permission management with CN1 right.

Comment: If you do not want to ask permission at runtime, you can set your compiledSDKversion to android L. In that case your app will ignore all Marshmallow features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following build hint:

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
```

You can also add this to the cn1lib so it is injected automatically.

Comment: I did that eventually. But as I use Capture.has camera() why does CN1 automatically add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` and not the required permission that you mention?

Comment: OK I finally understood ... my misunderstanding! Indeed [Android Developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest) states that 
 > Note: If you are using the camera by invoking an existing camera app, your application does not need to request this permission.
That's why CN1 does not require this permission!

Comment: @Shai Why is the "<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />" ... >>> "false" <<< please clarify if this is a type  and would turn on or off the permission for the camera? (I'm having some trouble with my app and this would help. Thanks!)

Comment: false means it's not required but desired. Install won't fail and we can fallback to other functionality. True means the app won't work without that permission

Answer (score 2):

In the past, you add the permission you want to your manifest and then it is requested when your user attempts to install your app. As of Android 6.0+, this has changed. Now you can just request a permission when your app needs it for the first time. After the user grants you permission, you don't need to ask again next time. Some benefits of this include keeping your user aware of why you need specific permissions and not requesting permissions that you don't actually need.

You can read more about how to implement it here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

There is no way to use a phones camera without asking for permission at some point.

Comment: I saw that on android 6.0+ thanks. But in the current case Android 4.4.2 is involved which is still quite used (25% of all Android devices as [of November 2016](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is; if you're asking if you need to add it to your manifest, the answer is yes.

Comment: I am using [Codename One](www.codenameone.com) (Write once run anywhere) to develop my app. And they take care of writing the needed permissions depending on which Codename One methods I use. However they don't add permissions regarding what I write in the native implementation. **That's why I used a CN1 method which should have triggered the camera permission according to the doc but which did not indeed**. As I don't have direct access to the manifest, I had to provide a specific "build hint" called "android.xpermissions" and filled it with the camera persmission.

Comment: CN1 doesn't go through the native interface to determine what permissions are needed. It should go through the CN1 code, but it doesn't do that for a native interface.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. I confused the call to the existing camera app (what happens in CN1) which does not need Camera permission and the direct use of the Camera API which does. I mark @Shai's answer as correct since it answers the question title.