# How to automatically start video recording and stop automatically after a predefined time in Codename One after pressing a button?

Tags: audio, video, codenameone

Here is the code that I am trying, It works fine but the user has to press the record button of the camera and then stop recording the video and then again press the done button to successfully save the video. The audio recording starts automatically but has to be stopped manually. Is there any way to do this (stop recording and save the video/audio) automatically after recording for some specific time (say 30 seconds)?

protected void onMain_MainButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

```
    //Capture Video

    String Video = Capture.captureVideo();
    if(Video != null) {
        try {
            //Capture Audio

            String Audio = Capture.captureAudio();
            if(Audio != null) {
                try {
                    //Uploading to the Server

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Dialog.show("Error!", "Unable to upload Video and Audio to the Server.", "OK", null);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Dialog.show("Error!", "Unable to record Audio.", "OK", null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        Dialog.show("Error!", "Unable to record Video.", "OK", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Capture` API doesn't support it. For audio recording we have a recorder API that allows us fine grained control over audio capture. We don't have such a control for video recording at this time but I think [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697480/how-to-force-permission-android-permission-camera-to-be-added-to-manifest-in-c) is working on that.

We've been working on better [z-ordering of peer components](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/html-maps-z-order-peer-properties-update.html) which will make a lot of previously problematic use cases (such as augmented reality) far more practical. So this is probably something we'll add into Codename One as we move forward although I don't have an immediate ETA.