# How are default Codename One Manifest values generated (and how to change them)?

Tags: android, codenameone

While trying to build an Android app on Codename One I got a build error that included the following Manifest information:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.brooklynwebcenter.app"
  android:versionCode="100"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:minSdkVersion="15"
  android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"      android:targetSdkVersion="14"  />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application  android:label="MyApplication"  android:icon="@drawable/icon"  android:allowBackup="true" >
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>        <activity android:name="MyApplicationStub"
              android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:label="MyApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <receiver android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.LocalNotificationPublisher" >
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.BackgroundFetchHandler" android:exported="false" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneBackgroundFetchActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.location.CodenameOneBackgroundLocationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationHandler" android:exported="false" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.location.GeofenceHandler" android:exported="false" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.media.AudioService" android:exported="false" />    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
  </manifest>
```

A few questions:

1. Why does the `minSdkVerson` automatically equal `15`, yet the `targetSdkVersion` equals `14?
2. How do change the permissions? I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697480/how-to-force-permission-android-permission-camera-to-be-added-to-manifest-in-c) but have not been successful changing permissions, for example `android.permission.INTERNET`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Target SDK version defaults to 23 I'm guessing you changed something in the build hints or one of your cn1libs did that change.

Permissions are added implicitly based on the Codename One API's used. If you are using native code in you need to use the `android.xpermissions` build hint to add permissions manually.

The internet permission is always added implicitly since it's so basic, if you really don't need that permission you can use the build hint `android.removeBasePermissions=true`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't change any build hints; I only added a gradle dependency. Also, I didn't add any special cn1 libs. This is the 2nd project in which I've noticed this occurring. Could it be that maybe my cn1 plugin  needs updating? ALSO, how do I change one of the implicit permission values, such as `INTERNET`? I don't want to remove or add, simply change the value. Thanks again.

Comment: Please edit the post and include your build hints or codenameone_settings.properties contents. In what way do you want to change the permission? Notice that permissions in the XML don't matter as much with API 23+